# Missing necklace

Tags: story, mystery

This comes from a friend of mine that is going organize a code breaker scavenger hunt and this was a sample that he made himself. I have solved it and put the 2 hints that he gave in comments section when it took a while to figure out.

A woman known to be in possession of a stolen necklace of great value was tracked to this hotel room.  After taking her into custody, the detectives search the premises.   They find several items, including a bronze key (worn around the edges), a book on seafaring (pages 13, 22, and 37 had been cut out), a diving knife (exceedingly sharp) , and a calendar.  The suspect was extremely meticulous had marked several appointments in her calendar.  The most common events were meetings with a Benjamin Mano.  She had appointments with this person scheduled for Sunday at exactly midnight, Monday at 4:35:23PM, Wednesday at 11:05:56PM, Thursday at 3:04:24AM, Friday at 6:25:32PM, and Saturday at 2:44:30AM.   Written in

Although she left no notes on the meetings, and officers were unable to ever interrogate Mano, using this information, they found the stolen necklace.  Where was the necklace located?

Comment: Is the abrupt ending of one of the lines 'Written in' intentional?

Comment: Nope has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name Benjamin Mano, plus extra hints in comments, suggest that

> the answer is something involving **hands** (*mano* in Spanish), most probably **clock hands**.

The times we are given come to

> [image: 12:00:00]
>  [image: 4:35:23]
>  [image: 11:05:56]
>  [image: 3:04:24]
>  [image: 6:25:32]
>  [image: 2:44:30]
>
>  With [the tool I used](https://www.visnos.com/demos/clock) to make these images, I couldn't adjust the seconds hand. But, interestingly, in all cases except 3:04:24 and 2:44:30, the seconds hand would be pretty much exactly on top of the hours hand, while for the fourth image the seconds hand should be near 5 and in the sixth image it should be at 6.

Looking at the images thus obtained, we can see

> roughly some letters: `I`, `n`, `v`, `E`, `n`, `T`.

Perhaps this means that the necklace is

> hidden in the vent inside her hotel room?

---

**Old answer**

Perhaps the necklace is

> at the beach, between the high and low water marks.

The appointments in her calendar could be

> low tide times, when she can go to check the necklace. Presumably "Benjamin Mano" is some kind of wordplay, but I can't figure it out.

The pages torn out of the book might be

> the ones with some information about tides, since it's a book on seafaring.

Comment: Hint #1:  Mr. Mano was a Spaniard, and while his name matters, the key and the seafaring book do not.

Comment: Hint #2 When the lead detective was asked by how he solved the case he just said, "It was written all over the face."

Comment: As of right now your answer is wrong.

Comment: @TerryHontz I know, but I haven't made any decent progress towards an alternative answer. The hints suggest it's something to do with rot13(pybpx unaqf), but looking at the times given, I couldn't make any sense out of that. Edited with some possible progress.

Comment: U are so close revisit your clock idea, but if the program doesn’t do the seconds Maybe write it out on paper.

Comment: @TerryHontz I did consider where the second hand would be in each case, and mentioned that below the images and in the next spoilertag.

Comment: Try putting the clocks faces side by side and see if you see anything

Comment: @TerryHontz Oh, got it! Maybe ...

Comment: Great job!! It took me just as long to figure it out also